# DotNetOpenAuth Sample OpenID Error: No OpenID endpoint found

Tags: c#, openid, dotnetopenauth

Im using DotNetOpenAuth and when i call :

```
this.openIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest(userSuppliedIdentifier, realm, returnToUrl);
```

I get the error above... I am using my own OpenID Provider which i just have running in localhost.  Does anyone have any idea what that could be?  the internal exception says sequence contains no items or something like that.

I was thinking maybe i was pointing my RP to the wrong location where i have my localhost running.  Is it correct to have point the RP to the XRDS file ?

Thanks
Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `userSuppliedIdentifier` should typically be the URL of the OpenID Provider web site -- not directly at the XRDS file. The home page of the Provider should detect a call for an XRDS doc and respond appropriately. The OpenIdProvider[Mvc] samples demonstrate this.

Since you're hosting on localhost, a very likely problem is that the RP refuses to connect to localhost endpoints (security by default, as that isn't really a valid scenario when you're in production). So you have to whitelist localhost in your web.config file when you're developing locally. See the OpenIdRelyingParty[WebForms/Mvc] sample's web.config file for how to do that.

Comment: Hi Andrew, and thanks for the reply.   I have adde the OpenIDProviderMVC as my OP now.. but the problem still occurs.  What is the actual endpoint do you know?  I've tried i think every aspx file in the project :(..  also does the whitelist only have to be set up the OP? or does it have to set on the RP aswell?

Comment: The whitelist needs to be on the RP's web.config file. The OP doesn't need it (unless you want RP discovery to work). The URL you type into the RP is simply the OP's root URL (http://localhost:port/ that hosts the OP site.)

Comment: I appreciate the advice Andrew!  I don't have a direct link between the RP and the OP though.  I have an intermediary STS that communicates with the OpenID Provider.  So should I have the whitelist on the RP   whitelist or on the STS whitelist (i dont have a whitelist  on the STS)

Comment: The should appear on whatever site makes the call to `OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest`.